# Why does available memory varies while no launched application?

Tags: android, memory-management

I have an android application from  which we can launch other installed applications.This have a background service which execute always while running my application.When testing on some devices noticed that the service stops sometimes due to low memory while launching some applications like Camera,Gallery(Album) etc... So I tried

```
private boolean isRunningOutOfMemory(){
    MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Service.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
    final long appMemeory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    final long availableMemory = memoryInfo.availMem / 1048576L;
    final long memoryThreshold = ((memoryInfo.threshold * 2) + appMemeory) / 1048576L;
    return (availableMemory <= memoryThreshold);
}
```

Showed a dialog if the condition is true.This method is running always in the background.And this condition sometimes does not work successfully.That is the service stops before if the available memory greater than twice of threshold.

This available memory varies when there is no launched other applications(applications launched from mine).ie,the running application is mine.

What is the reason for this variation in available memory?

Is it possible to find the memory at which the service stops ?

How can i handle this situation efficiently?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check for the method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onLowMemory()

Comment: Hardik,this method does not work for me.So I posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android system can kill *any* process whenever it decides it wants more memory. You can add hints (such as marking a service "foreground"), but the system is free to kill it at any time.

Your background service isn't the only background service running. Most likely, many other applications set up services to run at scheduled intervals (hopefully using Android Alarms rather than wait() loops...) to fetch new data. Other applications may set up Broadcast Receivers that are instantiated and executed when intents are sent by the system or by Google Cloud Messaging.

It's highly dynamic. Your service (and entire application) needs to be prepared to be stopped at any point. Marking it "foreground" increases its priority, but you should only do this when the service is related to something the user has started, such as playing a song or downloading a file.

One more thing - never show a dialog from a service! This is very jarring to the user as it could happen while they're using any other application. If you need to inform the user about something happening in a service, send a Notification.